# Reactjs/Nextjs- how to redirect to another page using NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs/reactjs and need some help on how to redirect to a page

Folder structure

```
-Pages

  -business

    -location.js

    -selectlocation.js
```

The URL =http://myhost/business/**location**?city=Pensacola&state=FL

When the argument is missing, I want to redirect to **selectlocation**

How do I route to the selectlocation page from the location page when the argument is empty

This is a snippet of my code for **location.js**

```
export default class extends Component {
    static getInitialProps({ query: { city, state } }) {
        return { city: city, state: state };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Head>
                    <title>{title}</title>
                    <meta name="description" content={description} />
                </Head>

                <LayoutWithHeader
                    banner={false}
                    view="business"
                    link="location banner"
                    locationCity={this.props.city}
                    locationState={this.props.state}>
                    <Location />
                </LayoutWithHeader>
            </div>
        );

    }
}
```

Code for SelectLocation.JS

```
export default () => (
    <div>
        <Head>
            <title>Location</title>
        </Head>
        <LayoutWithHeader banner={true} title="Home / Business / Locations" >
            <SelectLocation />
        </LayoutWithHeader>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sample routing code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()


  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push('/some-path')
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go Somewhere
    </button>
  )
}
```

Please see the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) for further details.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a link for the user to select. I would like to route it automatically  to the page in the pages folder based on a condition

Comment: Thanks. but I am looking at the URL .. if it has no argument then I want to redirect.. no button or link. automatically redirect.

Comment: If you're using react hooks then you can make use of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to achieve that. In case class components use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).